# Why did Einstein include reflection of light from a moving mirror in his paper?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light, reflection, history

Einstein, in his 1905 relativity paper, allocates a section to the issue of reflection of light from a moving mirror and derives three formulas (angle, frequency, energy). What was his reason or motivation behind including this problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a historical question that will probably get better responses on the History of Science and Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: I assume you're referring to *Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies*. Einstein used this as an example of how problems in the optics of moving bodies can be reduced to a series of problems in the optics of bodies at rest and certain transformation rules. If you've read the section and that's not a sufficient answer for you, I think Dale is right, and I'd suggest adding a couple of sentences to that effect in your question on HSM SE.

Comment: @gs Was there experimental evidence for any of the resulting formulas at that time?

Comment: @gs  for example were observed and calculated aberration values in disagreement at that time https://www.fourmilab.ch/cship/aberration.html

Comment: @Maesumi formulae don't need evidence. The axioms from which the formulae are derived need evidence, and evidence for the relationships in formulae constitute evidence for the axioms from which they were derived - and for all other relationships which can be derived from the same axioms.